# Oracle - ddl of created preference

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a preference using ctx_ddl.create_preference but dont remember the attributes set while creating the preference. Is there any way we can get ddl of the created preference?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/aviews.htm

Answer (score 0):

CTX_PREFERENCES AND CTX_PREFERENCE_VALUES are the views you're looking for.